# EXCEL - Consultar lista e retornar valores

Tags: query, microsoft-excel, lista, índices

Tenho um banco de dados com as seguintes informações:
[image: BANCO DADOS PLANOS]

Preciso representar estas informações em gráfico, e surgiu a necessidade de criar uma consulta para buscar os valores de acordo com a semana e o mês selecionado.

Para isto, utilizei a fórmula *INDICE* na coluna do Plano/Projeto para retornar o nome dos planos (Ex: "*NA1_0835_021_REV1_9*") e depois utilizei *PROCV* para buscar os valores correspondentes a cada plano/projeto.

[image: CONSULTA_LISTA]

O meu problema: Como buscar *TODOS* os Planos referente à semana 1 de 2018, porém não sei como indicar onde começa e onde termina as LINHAS dentro da matriz selecionada para compor a fórmula *ÍNDICE*

```
=INDICE(MATRIZ;NUMERO_LINHA;NUMERO_COLUNA
```

Outra dificuldade é para automatizar a consulta de acordo com o ANO e SEMANA, onde posso vincular esses filtros dentro da consulta?

Answer (score -1):

Nessas circunstâncias, exatamente do jeito que sua planilha se encontra, eu deixaria as fórmulas de lado e faria o seguinte:

Abra o editor VBA, insira um novo módulo e cole o seguinte código:

```
Sub getProjetos()

Dim semana, ano, thisplan As String

ano = Range("C2")
semana = Range("C3")
thisplan = ActiveSheet.Name

    Range("A7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("Planos").Select
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo -1
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$I$1000000").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=semana
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$I$1000000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ano
    Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(thisplan).Select
    Range("A6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

***IMPORTANTE***: Execute o código na planilha onde deseja o resultado, e não na Planos.
Você pode criar um botão ao lado da caixa Ano e Semana e atribuir essa macro também.
Testa ai e me conta..